# OpenGL Selection Buffer - Use A Pointer to the Object Instead of an Unsigned Int?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am attempting to use the glSelectBuffer(GLsizei size, GLuint * buffer) method to select objects in a slightly different way then I believe is supported in C++ for OpenGL 3.1. Selection works great if I do everything as is specified online.

Instead of a GLuint*, I would like to actually store **pointers to my graphical objects themselves** in the selection buffer. This will allow me to easily emit signals based on selection which contain a pointer to that object. This seems like it will work OK when the size of a GLuint and the size of a pointer to my object (x86) line up, but seems like it will break when they do not (x64.)

I can accomplish this with another step, but I would rather not have to line up the selection ID -> object pointer if OpenGL will support this mechanism of selection with other data types.

Is what I am trying to do possible using OpenGL's selection mechanism? (Preferably in OpenGL 3.1, but future versions are applicable as well.)

Does my question make sense? Am I missing something in my explanation? So far, I have tried to make the selection buffer take longs instead of ints, and I receive a type checking error (as is expected.) Also, I did not see any overloaded methods for glSelectBuffer(), which makes me think this approach is not possible. I looked at gl.h to see the typedefs and to understand OpenGL's types more. I have also looked over similar questions on Stack Overflow - I apologize if the same question has been asked and I missed it.

Comment: If `sizeof(GLuint*)>sizeof(GLuint)`, I think you'll have to use a hashtable.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - Thanks, a hash will be the way to go if I have to line these up myself, as I suspect and DeadMG's helpful comment helps reinforce.

Comment: Or some hackery where you assert all objects being pointed at have 16 byte alignment, and assert your memory addresses will all be less than 16GB.

Comment: While that might work, I think dealing with the byte alignment and forcing this to work is not the best idea. However, I will try and keep that type of suggestion in mind for future cases when there is NO better alternative. I like the hash table alternative much more for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Preferably in OpenGL 3.1, but future versions are applicable as well

Selection mode has been removed from OpenGL-3 core and later versions. OpenGL is meant for drawing, and selection mode uses to fall back into software mode anyway, i.e. is not HW accelerated.

Just my suggestion: Don't use it.

Comment: Using an analytic solution in software (ray/geometry intersection) as your answer suggests would be cleaner. We lack intersect functions for much of our geometry as well as acceleration data structures to make processing intersections quick enough for large sets of geometry. This would require major, major, changes while adding an ancillary hash table to line up the selection ID and the actual object pointer would not. I may leave this question unaccepted for a while, as I think the hash table may be a short term solution and getting away from OpenGL's selection may be our long term solution.

Comment: This is the long term solution we are working towards. 

In the short term, we have a way to line up the selection ID -> object similar to the hash table suggestion. Thank you all very much for your ideas and help.